# passing a parameter to a form in FormView Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have a form called `MyForm`. I overrode the `__init__()` method.
Now I need to pass the `request.user` parameter when creating this form in `MyFormView`.

I want to do this:

```
class MyFormView(FormView):
    form_class = MyForm(request.user)
```

Do I have to override the `__init__` method of my view? If so, how?

Comment: look into `get_form_kwargs`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Override the view's [`get_form_kwargs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs) method:

```
class MyFormView(FormView):
    form_class = MyForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(MyFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

Comment: That was so quick that I can't accept your answer before 10 minutes xD thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

```py
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(MyFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    data = kwargs['data'].copy()  # convert it to a mutable
    data['user'] = self.request.user
    kwargs['data'] = data
    return kwargs
```

Comment: Please add a few sentences to explain what your code is doing, so you can get more upvotes for your answer.